# "as seen as" vs "as seem as"

Tags: word-choice, reported-speech, as

What is the difference between the phrases *as seen as* and *as seem as*?

If I want to say, consumption of alcohol is very common in parties, should I use *as seen as* social activity in parties, or *as seem as* social activity in parties?

Comment: Neither is correct. Do you mean, *as seen in*, or *is seen as*, perhaps? *As__as* is a comparison: *as white as snow*. Are you trying to make a comparison?

Comment: Thanks you, I try to give an example only, not comparison.

Comment: "Alcohol consumption seems to be a very common activity at parties."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as. "Consumption of alcohol is very common in parties. It is seen as a social activity." "Seem" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> **as seem as** is completely wrong

You should use **as seen** because with respect to the context given it seems to fit exactly.

> The word **seem** give the impression of being something or having a particular quality

Hence it's not wise to use it here in your example.